# Get only the initialized content from a slice

Tags: go, slice

I append an unknown number of items (arround 10.000) into a slice

```
le := 500
l := make([]string, le)
l = append(l, "a")
l = append(l, "b")
l = append(l, "c")
l = append(l, "d")
l = append(l, "...")

for i, v := range l{
    fmt.Printf("i:%d-v:%s\n", i, v)
}
```

After this my slide contains

```
i:0-v:
...
i:500-v:a
i:501-v:b
i:502-v:c
i:503-v:d
i:504-v:e
```

I'm looking for a way to get only the initialized items stored in the slice.
I want to be rid of `i:0-v:` to `i:499-v:`

I can get the desired result re-slicing `l`, to remove the first elements of the slice (the number of first elements dépends on the `length` parameter passed to the `make` method).

```
l = l[le:]
for j, k := range l{
    fmt.Printf("i:%d-v:%s\n", j, k)
}
```

My question is: Is it the right way to achieve this or is there a nicer way to get rid of the items not initialized, added during the append?

Comment: AFAIK, everything is initialized in Go. You want those elements of `l` which are non empty.

Comment: Yes you right, I want the element wich are initilized to their "zero value"...

Comment: initializing a slice of length 1 has absolutely no benefit in this example. if you don't know the final capacity, let `append` do it for you. If you do, initialize the capacity, not the length.

Comment: I used the size 1 just for my example here ( not a good idea ) when I faced this I was using a size 500

Comment: 500 isn't much. There's probably a lot more places you can save a couple microseconds than in worrying about slice allocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make an empty slice,

```
// create a slice with len 0
l := []string{}

l = append(l, "a")
l = append(l, "b")
l = append(l, "c")
l = append(l, "d")
l = append(l, "...")
```

will give an output,

```
i:0-v:a
i:1-v:b
i:2-v:c
i:3-v:d
i:4-v:...
```

[**Example**](https://play.golang.org/p/IGp-yBSRos)

Comment: Yes this works, but I have a huge list of items ( arround 10.000). Creating the slice with a 0 length will have an impact on performance ?

Comment: @Nirekin Not necessarily. When append function is is used, the sizes increase at a rate of 2^n. So the difference between starting with 0 and starting with size 1 would be one extra copy.

Comment: I used the size 1 just for my example here  when I faced this I was using a size 500.

Comment: For 10000 inserts, the time we would have to increase the sizes would be 10. Which practically wouldn't be degrading the performance.

Answer (score 3):

You may create a slice using 0 length and capacity provided, the builtin [`make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make) function takes an optional 3rd parameter being the capacity:

```
l := make([]string, 0, 1000) // Use a capacity that is enough for you
```

This way you can append elements without `append()` having to reallocate (and implicitly copy) the contents if the current capacity is not enough to perform the append.

Also note that it is more efficient to set elements using indexing than appending (by using `append()` you have to assign the returned slice header back even though most of the time it doesn't change):

```
c, l := 0, make([]string, 1000) // Use a length that is enough for you

l[c], c = "a", c+1
l[c], c = "b", c+1
l[c], c = "c", c+1
l[c], c = "d", c+1
l[c], c = "e", c+1

// We're done: slice the slice:
l = l[:c]

for i, v := range l {
    fmt.Printf("i:%d-v:%s\n", i, v)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SV8esr8Wi9)):

```
i:0-v:a
i:1-v:b
i:2-v:c
i:3-v:d
i:4-v:e
```

Also note that in practice when you fill your slice with values you receive from somewhere, the manual counter handling is not needed, a loop takes care of that. For example:

```
c := 0
for ; c < 5; c++ {
    l[c] = string('a' + c) // Acquire next element to store in the slice
}

// We're done: slice the slice:
l = l[:c]
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kmhab8IUUW).

Note that you can only use this though if you create a slice that you're sure won't be small, else `l[c]` would give you a runtime panic when `c` reaches the length.